# Blackfire PHP Probe cannot locate php-cli

Tags: php, centos, cpanel, blackfire

While attempting to install **Blackfire.io PHP Probe** on my ***CentOS*** server by entering the follow command `sudo yum install blackfire-php` I received the following error:

```
Error: Package: blackfire-php-1.8.0-1.x86_64 (blackfire)
           Requires: php-cli
Error: Package: blackfire-php-1.8.0-1.x86_64 (blackfire)
           Requires: php-common >= 5.3
```

The odd thing is that I have *php-cli* and *php-common* already installed on my server.

By entering `php-cli -v`, I received:

```
PHP 5.5.31 (cli) (built: Jan 25 2016 09:03:41)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
with XCache v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2014, by mOo
with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.7.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd.
with XCache Cacher v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2014, by mOo
with Suhosin v0.9.36, Copyright (c) 2007-2014, by SektionEins GmbH
```

Any ideas or suggestions why Blackfire is unable to recognize that *php-cli* and *php-common*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of patience with researching and contacting directly with the server company (that was hosting the platform). I was finally told "**Blackfire is not compatible with the cPanel php.**"

So then, I decided to contact *Blackfire* and after a bit of back and forth I was then told the following by them:

> I'm not aware on anything on our side making Blackfire incompatible with cPanel.
>   However it seems they reworked the PHP "natural" way of installing extensions so I guess you should probably contact them to get more information.

*Which obviously, I already did.*

> However, if you have full root access to the VPS, then I guess the manual installation procedure should work with some minor adjustments.
>   The main idea is to download the proper so, put in in the PHP extension directory and add the blackfire.ini file.

In a nutshell, I was not able to properly fix the problem on my existing cPanel installation.

**So *warning***, if you're using cPanel, forget about Blackfire. Sadly, at the moment they're not compatible.

Hopefully this saves some people a lot of time.

Note, if someone ends up reading this and actually comes up with a solution and can provide *step-by-step* instructions, I will gladly change your response as an accepted answer :]

Answer (score 1):

Also blackfire does not work if ioncube is installed. Which is in your case:

> Known incompatibilities Please note that PHP compiled with debug are
>   not supported and that the Probe may conflict with XDebug or XHProf;
>   disable those extensions when enabling the Probe. The Probe conflicts
>   with some PHP extensions like Pinba or IonCube.